# Problema com requisição Ajax via jQuery - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto particular e comecei a desenvolver um calendário para colocar nesse projeto, porém, ao enviar a data selecionada pelo usuário ou de forma automática quando ele entra na página, para ser tratada, não consigo resgatar o dado enviado pelo Ajax para o PHP pelo método POST e nem GET. Quando tento capturar esse dado que eu enviei para o PHP da seguinte forma `print_r($_POST)` é mostrado na tela uma array vazia, ou seja, que não contém nem um elemento dentro dela. **Estou executando o calendário pelo próprio apache do PHP, ou seja, php -S localhost:3333, não sei se poderia interferir, porém, toda informação é válida**

Estou enviando o dado Ajax diretamente para a index.php que é onde contém o calendário, **pois quando eu for colocar dentro do meu projeto**, vou ter que enviar para a própria view que está sendo executada, para eu resgatar no controller, pois estou fazendo o projeto em estrutura MVC.

Vou colocar meu código agora e está tudo contido dentro da mesma pasta, pois o calendário que criei é só um protótipo para checar se iria da certo e se iria funcionar, **não está contido no projeto que está com a estrutura MVC, é apenas um protótipo para checar se iria dar certo**, porém, estou com problema no método Ajax.

**index.php**

```
<?php
  // Solicitando todos os dados enviado pelo método POST
  print_r($_POST);
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteudo">
    
        <div class="areaCalendario">
      <div class="mesSelect">
        <h4></h4><img src="dropDown.svg">
      </div>
      
      <div class="calendario">
        <header>
          <h2 class="ano"></h2>
          <a class="ButtonPrevious"><</a>
          <a class="ButtonNext">></a>
        </header>
        <table class="mes">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="mesSelecionado">Jan</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado">Fev</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado">Mar</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado">Abr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mesSelecionado">Mai</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado">Jun</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado">Jul</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado" >Ago</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mesSelecionado" >Set</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado" >Out</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado" >Nov</td>
              <td class="mesSelecionado" >Dez</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /*
  * 
  * Função global para fazer requisições ajax e enviar as informações para o 
  * servidor
  */
  function getAjax(date) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: {'date':date},
      dataType: 'html',
      success: d => {
        console.log(d)
      },
      error: erro => {
        console.log(erro)
      }
    })
  }

  /*
  * getDaysCalender(mes, ano)
  * Seleciona o mês e o ano atual, converte esses valores para string e apresenta
  * esses valores ao usuário.
  */
  function getDaysCalender(mes, ano) {
    monthSelect = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun','Jul', 
    'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'];

    document.querySelector('.mesSelect h4').innerHTML = monthSelect[mes];
    document.querySelector('.ano').innerHTML = ano;
    
    // percorrer as tds para selecionar o mes atual
    const table = document.querySelectorAll(".mes td");
    for(let i=0; i < table.length; i++){
      if(table[i].innerText === monthSelect[mes]) {
        table[i].classList.add("tdActive");
      }
    
    }
  
    

    return `${mes+1}-${ano}`;
  }

  /*
  * Selecionando o mês atual e o ano atual para ser enviada para o php por
  * requisições ajax
  */

  let dt = new Date();
  let month = dt.getMonth();
  let year = dt.getFullYear();
  // Capturando a informação do calendário
  let date = getDaysCalender(month, year);
  // envia por requisição ajax para ser tratado no php.
  getAjax(date)
  

  /*
  *  Selecionando o próximo ano ou o ano anterior
  */

  const btnPrev = document.querySelector(".ButtonPrevious");
  const btnNext = document.querySelector(".ButtonNext");

  btnPrev.onclick = () => {
    year--;
    document.querySelector('.ano').innerHTML = year;
  }

  btnNext.onclick = () => {
    year++;
    document.querySelector('.ano').innerHTML = year;
  }

  /*
  * selectDate(mes)
  * Seleciona a data que o usuário requisitou
  */

  function selectDate(mes) {
    // Para converter o mes para numero
    monthSelect = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun','Jul', 
    'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'];
    // Para trazer o ano que foi selecionado
    let yearSelect = document.querySelector('.ano').innerHTML;
    // Seleciona o mes que foi selecionado junto com o ano para deixar a class active
    const table = document.querySelectorAll(".mes td");
    for(let i=0; i < table.length; i++){
      if(table[i].innerText === mes) {
        document.querySelector('.mesSelect h4').innerHTML = mes;
        table[i].classList.add("tdActive");
      }
    }

    // Transformando o mês em numero
    let mesNum = null;
    for(let i=0; i<=monthSelect.length; i++) {
      if(monthSelect[i] == mes) {
        mesNum = i+1;
      }
    }

    // Enviar essa informação para o php para fazer a filtragem do mês e ano
    return `${mesNum}-${yearSelect}`;
  }
  
  /*
  * Seleciona o mês e o ano no calendário e envia esses dados para serem tratados
  * na função selectDate
  */
  
  $('.mesSelecionado').click((e) => {
    $('.mesSelecionado').removeClass('tdActive');
    // Caputrando o mes escolhido e enviando para a function
    let monthSelect = e.target.innerHTML;
    // Recebendo os dados da function
    let date = selectDate(monthSelect);
    //Envia o ados para o getAjax para enviar via ajax para o php
    getAjax(date)
    // Fechando calendario após selecionar o mes e o ano
    $('.calendario').slideToggle();
  })


  /*
  * Abrindo o calendário quando for solicitado pelo usuário
  */

  $('.mesSelect').click((e) => {
    $('.calendario').slideToggle();
  })


  /*
  * Executando métodos quando a página for carregada
  */
  $(document).ready(() => {
    // Deixando o calendario com display none
    $('.calendario').hide();
  })

}, false);
```

**Comentários finais**

o Ajax funciona perfeitamente, pois ele mostra no console do navegador toda a index.php, que é o comando enviando caso a requisição seja sucedida, ou seja, o comando success do ajax.

Ao enviar o dado via Ajax para o PHP e executar o seguinte comando dentro da index.php ````print_r($_POST)```, ele apresenta uma array vazia, porém o success mostra no console toda a index.php com essa array preenchida, segue a imagem para visualizar como fica ao solicitar e enviar o dado --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0civ.png

No elements que são os códigos html executado, mostra uma array vazia, segue a imagem de como mostra no elements --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvT3Z.png

Agora na network que é onde mostra todas as execuções feita na aplicação, no **localhost** mostra a array vazia, segue a imagem de como é mostrado --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvrGE.png só que na própria network tem a **index.php** que mostra que a array está preenchida como foi solicitado pelo método `print_r($_POST)`, segue a imagem de como é mostrado a network da index.php --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrkT3.png dentro da network é mostrada que foi feita a requisição com sucesso, porque apresenta **xmlrequest.js**.

**Considerações finais**

Então, não sei se minha linha de raciocínio é valida e está correta, porém, o que parece é que o localhost não consegue se "atualizar" para receber a index.php com os dados, ou seja, em outra palavras é como se o localhost não estivesse olhando para a index.php e percebendo que teve alteração, logo ele não consegue fornecer esse dado solicitado ao usuário no navegador, que é o que estou querendo nesse momento, para poder tratar essa data e futuramente jogar para o modal, para poder efetuar a manipulação do dado e resgatar os dados contido no banco de dados. Com isso, se minha linha de raciocínio estiver correta, não sei como resolver. KKKKKKKKKKKK :D

Comment: Deixa eu entender, quando entra na página mostra vazio, e quando chama ajax mostra o Array? é isso?

Comment: Não, quando entra na página mostra vazio e o Ajax é chamado automaticamente, assim que a página carrega, porque o javascript pega a mês atual, por exemplo 6/2020 e já envia para a index.php, ai quando o usuário for fazer uma filtragem para o mês anterior pro exemplo, ele abre o calendário e seleciona o mês anterior, ai o ajax manda novamente pela mesma variável #_POST(date) a requisição do usuário, no caso 05/2020, entendeu ?

Comment: Faltam detalhes: Mas isso está estranho dataType: 'html'... normalmente 'json' ou 'xml', acho que você está usando 'json'....

Comment: Eu já tentei pelo método json, não funcionou, sim está estranho porque sempre fiz assim e sempre deu certo não usando o dataType html e sim json, mas nem JSON está funcionando, quais os detalhes que está faltando ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro estava na minha falta de atenção usando o recurso Ajax, esqueci que tudo que eu 'printar' no PHP, ele não vai mostrar nada para o cliente mais sim para o Ajax.

Com isso, quando eu solicitava um print_r($_POST) ele não mostrava para o cliente, mais sim para o Ajax, o que está totalmente correto e faz total sentido, já que a ideia do Ajax é processar dados sem fazer relaod, fazendo com que minha pergunta fosse totalmente equivocada, pois não tem 'erro' no meu código, mas sim na minha visão de pensar sobre o Ajax, ou seja, meu código está totalmente correto, mas a minha visão sobre o Ajax que estava equivocada, pois é como se todo o 'print' que eu desse no meu php, o Ajax pegasse e não 'passasse' essa informação para o html, só se eu mandasse ele jogar essa informação em alguma div do html.

A array vazia que é mostrada para o usuário ao solicitar o `print_r($_POST)`, faz total sentido, já que para o php conseguir mostra aquela array preenchida deveria ser feito um reload, como é feito ao enviar um formulário ao php. Porém, no ajax, não é preciso fazer reload. Com isso, no Ajax a ideia é enviar para o php o post, sem precisar fazer um reload na página, fazendo com que você consiga manipular esse post no php, mas não consiga apresentar na tela do usuário com o `print_r($_POST)` mas sim para o Ajax.

Muito obrigado aos que tentaram ajudar e deram atenção a esse problema, peço desculpa pela minha falta de atenção, mas depois disso meu cérebro conseguiu entender como funciona o Ajax perfeitamente kkkkkkkkk, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar isso no início do seu script PHP:

header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: Gerou o código fonte, da index.php com o array vazio, olha ai o código de como ficou --> https://i.imgur.com/MDV8jOD.png